# Twitter in Node Red auth credentials issue

Tags: twitter, ibm-cloud, node-red

I'm new to Node-red and Bluemix

I'm trying to get a Twitter feed

I added the Twitter input node to the workspace.

I can't get the "add new twitter credentials" working :(

I click on the pen next to the select box, and new screen opens to auth that I use the twitter credentials (logged in as a Twitter user in another tab in EDGE browser).  I accept and get the success message and that I can close the window.

However, nothing happens in the Node-red editor.  If I deploy, I get an error message in the debug window:  Missing twitter credentials

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks
Nico

Comment: What happens if you use a different browser?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your node configuration?  Are you searching for specific users?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks,

the problem was Microsoft Edge.

Chrome in Android works like a charm for Node-red on Bluemix :)